# Convert URL to Path without throwing an exception

Tags: java, url, path, nio

One common case I have is that I want to do some IO operation on a local resource in my project. The easiest way to access local resources is `getClass().getResource("path")` which returns an URL.* The easiest way to to IO stuff is through `Files.XXX` which requires a `java.nio.Path` most of the time.

Converting an URL into a Path is easy: `Paths.get(url.toURI())`. Sadly, this may throw a `URISyntaxException` I now have to catch. I don't understand why, this is annoying, ugly, I never got one and I hate it.

Now to the real question: Are there alternative ways to access local resources as Path or to convert an URL to a Path without throwing exceptions?

---

- I know that there is `getResourceAsStream()` too, but a simple `InputStream` often isn't enough.

Comment: There is no `MalformedURIException` (there is a `MalformedURLException`). Do you mean `URISyntaxException`?

Comment: Yes I do. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the Javadoc of [`URL.toURI()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toURI()) you'll see:

> Returns a [`URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) equivalent to this `URL`. This method functions in the same way as `new URI (this.toString())`.
>
> ...

The method is the same as calling the `URI(String)` constructor which is where the possible `URISyntaxException` is coming from. However, if you look at the `URI` class you'll find a static factory method: [`URI.create(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#create(java.lang.String)). The Javadoc for this method states:

> Creates a `URI` by parsing the given string.
>
> This convenience factory method works as if by invoking the [`URI(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) constructor; any [`URISyntaxException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URISyntaxException.html) thrown by the constructor is caught and wrapped in a new [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) object, which is then thrown.
>
> ...

This means both `URL.toURI()` and `URI.create(String)` call `new URI(String)`. The difference being that `URI.create(String)` throws the *unchecked* `IllegalArgumentException` which means you don't have to use `try-catch` blocks everywhere. You can use the following:

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource");
Path path = Paths.get(URI.create(resource.toString()));
```

Answer (score -3):

```
URL url=getClass().getResource("/getresources/test.txt");
File f=new File(url.toURI());
```

Try this.

Comment: `url.toURI()` still throws a checked exception.

Comment: This does not work for multiple reasons: I don't need a File, I need a Path. Files are deprecated and won't work with the resources packed in a jar. And as mentioned above, calling toURI() on an URL still throws an Exception